# Dll C++ | Llamada de un objeto de un tipo de clase sin ninguna función de conversión u operador() adecuados para el tipo de puntero o función

Tags: c++, dll

Estoy intentando hacer un dll para poder utilizar una clase 'Net' que hice pero al intentar inicializar la clase en la función 'inicializar' no me deja el lenguaje. Que puede estar pasando?

Los módulos son:

PruebaRed.H

```
#pragma once
#ifdef PRUEBARED_EXPORTS
#define PRUEBARED /*extern "C"*/ __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PRUEBARED __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include "Modulo0.h"
#include <vector>
vector <int> topologia;
Net red;

Matrix salida;
PRUEBARED void inicializar();
```

PruebaRed.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "PruebaRed.h"
#include "Modulo0.h"

void inicializar()
{
    topologia.push_back(2);
    topologia.push_back(3);
    topologia.push_back(3);
    topologia.push_back(2);
    red(2, topologia);
}
```

En el modulo "Modulo0.h" está la clase Net

Error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llamada de un objeto de un tipo de clase sin ninguna función de conversión u operador() adecuados para el tipo de puntero o función

Estoy trabajando en visual studio

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que haga esta línea? `red(2, topologia);`

Comment: Quiero que inicialice el objeto red de la clase 'Net' con los parámetros que le estoy pasando (2, topología). No publiqué el código de la clase Net para no hacer el post demasiado extenso, pero es una clase para crear una red neuronal

Comment: Mira, no hace falta que publiques todo el codigo. Pero si suficiente para que yo pueda pegarlo en mi ordenador, compilarlo y ver tu problema. Si el código es muy extenso, trata de reproducir el problema en otro lado, y nos compartes eso

Comment: Y si no pasas todo, puedes minimo compartir el lugar en el que defines el operador()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siendo `red` una instancia de clase, esto

```
red( 2, topologia );
```

es entendido por el compilador como una llamada a `Net::operator()`. Si la clase no proporciona ese operador, el compilador emitirá un error ... que es justamente lo que te está pasando.

Entiendo que lo que quieres es *inicializar* la instancia. Y eso ha de hacerse **en el momento de crearla**, llamando a uno de sus constructores.

Si la instancia ya está creada, tienes 2 opciones:

#### 1. Opción fácil, lógica, y lo que deberías hacer:

Simplemente, usa el operador de asignación:

```
   red = std::move( Net( 2, topologia ) );
```

<sub>En este caso concreto, la llamada a `std::move( )` es irrelevante, pero me gusta ponerla para *auto-documentar* lo que hago.</sub>

#### 2. Opción mala. Cuidado con ella. Solo para casos excepcionales.

Puedes reutilizar las direcciones de memoria ya ocupadas por la instancia. Pero, como ya ha sido creada e inicializada, tienes que *destruirla* primero:

```
#include <new>

red.~Net( );
new ( &red )( 2, topologia );
```

Observa que es necesario incluir la cabecera `<new>`.

**MUCHO CUIDADO AL HACER ESTO**. El compilador *no sabe nada de ello*. Desde su punto de vista, la instancia se creó en un determinado ámbito **y se llamará a su destructor al salir de él**.

- Si llamas a `new ...` sin llamar al destructor primero, es un comportamiento indefinido.
- Si llamas al destructor sin volver a llamar al constructor, cuando la ejecución salga del ámbito en el que se creó la variable, es comportamiento indefinido.

Además, puedes encontrarte con otros problemas *raros* y difíciles de depurar, debido a las optimizaciones que realiza el compilador. En estas ocasiones, el declarar la variable como

```
volatile Net red;
```

suele ayudar, al avisar al compilador de que su contenido puede variar fuera de su control. Claro que entonces el compilador dejará de aplicar muchas optimizaciones sobre la variable en cuestión.

Lo dicho: **USA LA OPCIÓN 1** :-)

<sub>No forma parte de la pregunta, pero **usar variables globales es una idea nefasta**. Acostumbrate a **no usarlas**.</sub>